# N-dimensional definition of elasticity

Tags: calculus, economics

The elasticity of a differentiable function $f(x)$ is defined as:

$\varepsilon(x) = \frac{x}{f(x)}f'(x)$

What is the general form of this definition for N-dimensions, i.e., where $\vec{x}$ is a vector instead?

Comment: If I were to guess how to generalise this mathematically, I'd say $$\epsilon(\vec x)=\frac1{f(\vec x)}\vec x\cdot\nabla f(\vec x)=\vec x\cdot\nabla (\log f(\vec x))$$But I am not an expert in this field

Comment: @JohnDoe I don't think that's quite it, you can't divide by a vector, nor can you take the gradient of a vector valued function. Maybe magnitude of vector instead? I assume your arrows mean vectors.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for: http://www.rmi.ge/~kade/LecturesT.Kadeishvili/MathEconomics/Term3/Week4PartialsLEC.pdf. See section 1.3.3.

Comment: @LordVader007 $f(\vec x)$ is not a vector, it is a vector-valued scalar function. The $i$th component of the gradient is defined as $$[\nabla f(\vec x)]_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(\vec x)$$Then we'd have $$\varepsilon(\vec x)=\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\log f(\vec x))$$

Comment: @JohnDoe ok that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.